# Express a matrix as a vector multiplied by its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

Suppose I have an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with positive real entries. Is it possible to find an $n \times 1$ vector $v$ such that

$$ vv^T = A $$

where $v^T$ is the transpose of $v$?

Is it possible to use singular value decomposition or any technique to achieve this?

Comment: If and only if $A$ has rank $0$ or $1,$ and if so, the decomposition should be easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rank of $vv^T$ is 1 or 0, so only square matrices of rank 1 or 0 can have such a representation.

If $A=0$ then $v=\vec 0$.

In general if $v=(a_1,...,a_n)^T$ then $vv^T$ has rows $a_1v^T,..., a_nv^T$, so you can find $v$ by looking at the diagonal entries of $A$.

Comment: is there a proof of this available somewhere?

Comment: Proof of what?${}{}$

Comment: A proof that if rank($A$) = $1$, then $\exists v$ such that $vv^t = A$ (the rank $0$ case is trivial).

Comment: That statement is not correct. $A=vv^T$ implies $rank(A)=1 or 0$ but the converse is false.

Comment: Yes only for $A$ of rank 1 or 0 such a decomposition can exist. It does not say that it **must** exist in this case.

Comment: For instance notice that $vv^T$ is symmetric, hence if $A$ has rank 1, but it is not symmetric, such $v$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

$vv^T$ has rank $\le 1,$ so such a decomposition exists only if $A$ has rank $\le 1.$

If the decomposition exists, $v$ is formed from taking  square roots of the entries on the diagonal of $A$ since $a_{i,i}=v_i^2.$ You will get $2^k$ possible $v$'s where $k$ is the number of non-zero entries.

Comment: Is it $2^k$ because we can take either the positive or negative root?

Comment: There are at most two values of $v$ to be considered.

Comment: is there a proof of this available somewhere?

Comment: If $A$ is in this form and $v=(a_1,...,a_n)^T$ then the rows of $A$ are $a_iv^T$.  Suppose row number $i$ is not zero, then the entry $A_{ii}=a_i^2>0$. Then there are two possible values of $a_i$ which gives two possible values of $v^T$ (which is the $i$th row divided by $a_i$).

Comment: By the way, both of these values of $v$ give $A=vv^T$.